# Automatic Recording of an iOS app

Tags: ios, automated-tests, record

Is there a way/service or a bunch of tools that enable to automatically traverse an iOS app and simulate taps AND record the screen in a video/gif? the app links can be through deep linking or any other mechanism

in a web environment, it can be done with some javascript, capybara, and some tools (offline or online). Can this be done (in production app or in simulator, or even through some other app)

Comment: What about the Xcode automation instrument?

Comment: Do you mean recording iOS app activity in runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, bundled with Xcode there is Instruments, in Instruments there is a tool called [Automated UI Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html) that helps in testing UI. You can create your own JS test, or record a set of functions to be replicated later.
To make a screen recording you can use the QuickTime screen capture functionalities.
More info [here](http://sohail.io/2014/09/20/xcode-6-and-running-uiautomation-test-from-the-command-line/).